Change zorder of 3D PolyCollection in Matplotlib
My graph looks like this:
Graph with improper zorder
How do I make it look like this from the other side?
Graph with proper zorder
Attached is the relevant code.
def polygon_under_graph(x, y):
    """
    Construct the vertex list which defines the polygon filling the space under
    the (x, y) line graph. This assumes x is in ascending order.
    """
    return [(x[0], 0.), *zip(x, y), (x[-1], 0.)]

a_verts, g_verts, m_verts = [], [], []
a_verts.append(polygon_under_graph(xs, a_ys))
g_verts.append(polygon_under_graph(xs, g_ys))
m_verts.append(polygon_under_graph(xs, m_ys))
a_poly = PolyCollection(a_verts, facecolors=['b'], alpha=1.0)
g_poly = PolyCollection(g_verts, facecolors=['y'], alpha=1.0)
m_poly = PolyCollection(m_verts, facecolors=['r'], alpha=1.0)
ax.add_collection3d(g_poly, zs=2, zdir='y')
ax.add_collection3d(m_poly, zs=1, zdir='y')
ax.add_collection3d(a_poly, zs=0, zdir='y')
plt.plot(xs, g_ys, zs=2, zdir='y', color="black", zorder=4)
plt.plot(xs, m_ys, zs=1, zdir='y', color="black", zorder=2)
plt.plot(xs, a_ys, zs=0, zdir='y', color="black", zorder=0)

The only example of what I am looking to do is from here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/polys3d.html

You can try ax.computed_zorder = False docs.  That way, matplotlib will be stopped from trying to compute its own z-order.  The automatic z-order uses the centers of the objects to set an order, but that doesn't work well in many situations.
